# Creating Dictionaries within a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary that has entries like an address book.  I'm reading through some data with re.compile.  I get the elements in the different groups and add them to the dictionary.  But at the end, I am only left with the last 'people'.  It overwrites all the other entries.  Is there a way to create this long list of records with the same keys?

```
addressbook = {}

format = re.compile(r'''(([A-Z][a-z]*)([\,][\s])([A-Z][a-z]*) 
    ([\,][\s])(\d{3})([\.])(\d{3})(\.)(\d{4})''', re.VERBOSE)

for q in format1.findall(data):
    lname = q[1] 
    addressbook['lastname'] = lname
    fname = q[3]
    addressbook['firstname'] = fname
    ph1 = q[5]
    ph2 = q[7]
    ph3 = q[9]
    phone = ph1 +  ph2  + ph3
    addressbook['phonenumber'] = phone
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
{‘people’: 
{‘firstname’: ‘Joe’, ‘lastname’: ‘Smithe’, ‘phone’: ‘5563036594’}, 
{‘firstname’: ‘John’, ‘lastname’: ‘Lesley’, ‘phone’: ‘5961236448’},
{‘firstname’: ‘Betty’, ‘lastname’: ‘Larking’, ‘phone’: ‘3133426598’}
}
```

Comment: can you add some of your input?

Answer (score 0):

store a list of  dicts, one for each person:

```
addressbook = {"people": []}

for q in format1.findall(dataIn):
    d = {'lastname': q[1], 'firstname': q[3],
         d['phonenumber']: "{}{}{}".format(q[5], q[7], q[9])}
    addressbook["people"].append(d)
```

If you have exactly ten elements, you can unpack:

```
addressbook = {"people": []}
for _, fn, _, ln, _, ph1, _, ph2, _, ph3 in format1.findall(dataIn):
    addressbook["people"].append({'lastname': ln, 'firstname': fn,
                                'phonenumber': ph1 + ph2 + ph3})
```

If you are using the other elements elsewhere, replace each `_` with a useful name.

Comment: Friend.  `{"people":{'5563036594':{'name':'Joe', .........}}}` 
list do you think a good choice? how quickly, will be upgraded. My secondary key :PhoneNumber( Because unique..)(i hope all people got phone number :)) )

Comment: @SDilmac. the OP wants multiple dicts with the same keys, if they want a structure like the desired output they need a list,  would you memorise every phone number when you want to access a person?

Comment: Yes. It's very hard fixing, when a data corrupted. waste resource, don't waste time, time is everything!

Comment: Thanks for info, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need a list:

```
people_format = re.compile(r'''([A-Z][a-z]*)(?:,\s)([A-Z][a-z]*) 
    (?:,\s)(\d{3})(?:\.)(\d{3})(?:\.)(\d{4})''', re.VERBOSE)

people = []
for lastname, firstname, ph1, ph2, ph3 in people_format.findall(data):
    people.append({
        'lastname': lastname,
        'firstname': firstname,
        'phonenumber': ph1 + ph2 + ph3
    })
addressbook = {'people': people}
```

Comment: `for lastname, firstname, ph1, ph2, ph3` is not going to work

Comment: why not? `findall` returns a list of tuples.

Comment: there are at least ten items based on the OP's code

Comment: I've improved the regular expression.

Comment: Looks great.  Working with this now.  Thank you for the answer.